# Issue with D3 Smooth Zoom in of globe on click of plot

Tags: animation, d3.js, svg, zooming, webgl-globe

I have created D3 globe.
I am stuck in issue, right now on click on plot, Map zoom in but it is not smooth zoom in.
I need to zoom in map with smooth transition.
http://projectsdemo.net/globe/v4/

```
globe.focus = function(d, k) { d3.selectAll('.globe').transition()
  .duration(2000)
  .tween("transform", function() {
    var centroid = d3.geo.centroid(d);
    var r = d3.interpolate(projection.rotate(), [-centroid[0], -centroid[1], 0]);
     return function(t) {
        //projection.rotate(r(t));
         pathG.selectAll("path").attr("d", path);
         var clipExtent = projection.clipExtent();
        //projection.scale(1).translate([0, 0]).clipExtent(null);
        //var b = path.bounds(d);
        var minScale = 270,
        maxScale = minScale * 5;
        projection.rotate(r(t)).scale(Math.max(minScale, Math.min(maxScale, k)))
          .translate([width / 2, height / 2])
          .clipExtent(clipExtent);
         }
  });
```

Comment: There is no zoom on click.

Comment: Please check now its working

Comment: http://projectsdemo.net/globe/v4/

Comment: Nope, nothing happens here.

Comment: Can you please do hard refresh or clear browse cache as it working in my browser

Comment: It's working now. I'm seeing your source code, but it's very difficult to help without being able to test the changes. I hope someone else can help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your rotate is transistioning because of this:

```
.rotate(r(t))
```

Where `r` is an interpolate function and `t` is the current step in the transition.  It looks like your scale though:

```
.scale(Math.max(minScale, Math.min(maxScale, k)))
```

is just set to the same value at every step in the transition.

You need to set up a separate interpolate function for the scale:

```
var r = d3.interpolate(projection.rotate(), [-centroid[0], -centroid[1], 0]),
    r2 = d3.interpolate(project.scale(), Math.max(minScale, Math.min(maxScale, k)));
```

Then, use this in your transition:

```
projection.rotate(r(t))
  .scale(r2(t))
  ...
```